# Is there an error in my XPath locator for the provided HTML?

Tags: html, selenium

I am currently trying to type a filter into a search bar and then select the option that comes up in a field. My understanding is that by sending the keys to filter the selection I would be able to click the result. I have tried these three different lines of code to select the option 'Date of Donation' and am having no luck. The errors I get are that the element was not in scroll view or a timeout error when it cannot be located. Is there some other way to locate this option and then double click on it?

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//option[contains(text(),'Date of Donation')]").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[id='fieldsDisplay']/optgroup[6]/option[4]")

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div/div[5]/form/div[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/select[2]/optgroup[6]/option[4]")))
```

The HTML for this element of the form looks as such:

```
<option value="7313" fieldgroupid="373" fieldid="7313" fieldtype="DATE">
Date of Donation
</option>
```

I've included a picture of the form I am trying to access for further clarity:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmtJ4.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would try scrolling to the element with Javascript first, and see if that helps:

```
# locate the element
date_of_donation = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//option[contains(text(), 'Date of Donation')]")))

# scroll into view before clicking
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", date_of_donation)

# now click
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", date_of_donation)
```

It's also possible that this element exists within an `iframe`, in which case it would need to be switched to before interacting with the element.